# How to Jump to particular section using React router-dom Link

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, anchor, react-router-dom

`<Link to="/greetings#section2"/>`
When we use Link in react dom it is will jump to greetings page, but it cannot jump into a particular section as

`<a href="/greetings#section2"/>`
Did any one know how to do like this using LINK

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394#issuecomment-220221604

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it using `to` props:

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/greetings', hash: '#section2'}} />
```

But my question would be that why you're afraid using `<a>` tag in such case?

Comment: ```<a>``` can be used that's right but it will make complex to mix with <a> and <Link> ..
<Link> hash will not jump to specific part it will only add "#hashkey" with pathname.

Comment: What complexity you feel mixing <Link /> and <a /> ?

Comment: <a> tag rerenders the whole page while <Link> don't render the page......that's why